# How to write a key name in the type script interface if it has '-'

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, data-integrity

```
export interface team {
  football:Football
  table-tennis:TableTennis
}

export interface Football{
  goalPost:any
  ball:any
}

export interface TableTennis{
  bat:any
  ball:any
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encase the key name in quotes, similar to how you would do it in JSON

```
export interface team {
    football: Football,
    "table-tennis": TableTennis
    // use a string!
}

export interface Football {
    goalPost: any,
    ball: any
}

export interface TableTennis {
    bat: any,
    ball: any
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDqzAWzgG8AoOSudCCGAI0wBsmAuOAMVoeaYBoKVAEQxM9JsAC0qJEgQBnIewAqYicuCyFgygHpdcAK7y8mOPJhRkAcwCEZAL5kyoSLEQo0WXJ26MWpDpw1hDMAAoQFuyYSACeAlRw-mxwMbGOzq7Q8MioGDh4quLAGlrygYmMMNFxCVTJNekOQA)

Comment: Suppose this team interface is the response model of an api. Let's say teamResponse. How to access value of the key called table-tennis from teamResponse. Because teamResponse.table-tennis gives error

Comment: You use teamResponse["table-tennis"]

Comment: I declared a const tableTennis="table-tennis" and that solved my problem. I was able to access the bat using teamResponse.tableTennis.bat

Answer (score 0):

You would use quotes, like how you would in JavaScript:

```
export interface team {
    football: Football;
    "table-tennis": TableTennis;
}
```

Comment: But in that case how would I be able to access it from the response object.

Comment: @Sayan `response["table-tennis"]`?

Comment: Suppose this team interface is the response model of an api. Let's say teamResponse. How to access value of the key called table-tennis from teamResponse. Because teamResponse.table-tennis gives error. Incase of football we can access with teamResponse.football

Comment: You use teamResponse["table-tennis"]

Comment: In that case how I can I access bat or ball which is inside table-tennis interface. Like teamResponse["table-tennis"].bat doesn't work

Comment: See https://javascript.info/object and 
[What is a help vampire?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire)